# SELECT DISTINCT Returning Unexpected Values

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2016 database is using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  When I run this query...

```
select distinct x from (
select '²' as x
union all
select '2'
) y 

select distinct x from (
select N'²' as x
union all
select N'2'
) y
```

The VARCHAR version sees the two characters as being different; the NVARCHAR version sees them as being the same.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Fascinating. Simply fascinating. And stupid. But fascinating nonetheless.

Comment: Short answer is that collations and code pages are weird.

Comment: You might find more info under the concept of "Unicode character folding". I don't know enough to confirm that this applies specifically to superscripted characters. As far as I know there isn't a superscript combining character though.

Comment: I did a little more playing around and found all sorts of interesting things: a) both SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS fold some values together, but they do it in different ways; and b) the same collation yields different results for CHAR and NCHAR for the same characters.  Yuk.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, they are considered the uppercase and lowercase version of the same character as nvarchar.  If you run this case sensitive query:

```
select Distinct x from (
select N'2' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  as x
UNION ALL
select N'²' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS as x
) y
```

You will get this output:

```
x
2
²
```

Comment: Indeed!  As I noted above, though, it is odd that the collation for CHAR would be different than that for NCHAR for the same characters.

Comment: I agree with you completely about that. I considered it a minor bug after I discovered this. I only tried the case sensitive query because that made a perverse sort of logical sense.

Answer (score 1):

> The VARCHAR version sees the two characters as being different

Default `CoLLATE` `(COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)` of database is doing the trick here.

`COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` consider `varchar` value `'²'` and `'2'` as 2 different value.

In case of NVARCHAR  `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` consider '²' and '2' as same value.

It has nothing to do with ACSII or UNICODE

Comment: Leaving ASCII and UNICODE out of it, it strikes me as odd that the same collation for CHAR and NCHAR would yield different results for the same character values.