# Database Table considering different text values as same and duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6, code first migration workflow to set up my database. I have a table with one of its columns to contain unique values. I configured this column using fluent API as shown below.

```
Property(wrd => wrd.Text)
.IsRequired()
.HasMaxLength(100)
.HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("AK_AmWord_Text") { IsUnique = true }));
```

My problem is, when I try to insert test data, I discovered that the table is considering two Amharic words "ወደደ" and "እወዳለሁ" as duplicate values which cannot be inserted in the unique column. Obviously the two strings are not same and shouldn't have been considered as duplicates, but even I tried to insert the values manually in the table, but the two strings are being considered as same and duplicates.

What should I do to rectify this please? Thank you

Comment: What collation setting do you have on your database?  What datatype is your column?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and creating the database using code first, hence I did nothing to make setting regarding collation. I was assuming SQL uses Unicode by default and should recognize Amharic scripts. The specific column with the issue is declared as nvarchar when I check the table column

Comment: If you are using NCHAR/NVARCHAR, you will be storing Unicode characters.  HOWEVER, that has nothing to do with collation as different collations consider different Unicode characters to be the same.  I ran into the same problem with a slightly different spin just the other day -- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603172/select-distinct-returning-unexpected-values).